# Microsoft Band SDK - How to get the battery status?

Tags: microsoft-band

I would like to develop a Windows Phone App (C#) for the Microsoft Band and I need to get the current battery status from it. I cannot find anything in the documentation or the web.

Could someone help, please?

Thanks,
Marwin

Comment: I'm currently working on using reflection to call some internal methods on the SDK, to see if I can get the battery status that way. I can only imagine that's the way they did it. Will post results if I succeed. Already found a "power manager" on the internal code. Now trying to use it to communicate with the band.

Answer (score 1):

The battery status is not currently exposed by the SDK. You could raise that as feature request for a future release at http://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/

Comment: Any clue as to how https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/band-companion/9nblgggz36wv is managing to get the voltage and percentage than? Are they somehow decompiling and using some hidden functions?